# Can we see all followed questions on the user profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, bookmarks, favorites-notifications

On the user account page, can we show one more tab with 'following' questions and list all those questions, and whenever there is any activity on that question, the follower can be informed though the inbox?

Comment: I would second this feature request. The StackExchange Inbox, could have an additional tab showing details seen in the _Recent Activity_ page. Not an urgent need, but certainly a positive addition. I often favorite questions only never to see them again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You can add the question to your favorites. If I am not mistaken, edits and answers to the question will appear in your Stack Exchange inbox. It also appears under "favorites" tab in profiles.
2. You could add the question to your personal RSS feed.

Comment: 1: I think one can mark a question 'favorite' only when that user has done some activity (comment/answer) on that interesting question. In this case, since I  have not commented nor answered so this question will not be listed in my account.  2:Personal you mean stackoverflow account's  personal or my personal?

Comment: 1. Really? I'm not sure about that. I have a bunch of favorite questions that I have never touched. 2. Your personal personal RSS feed, if you have one. I use Mozilla Thunderbird, for example.

Comment: Aren't favorites defined by the favorite tags? I don't see any links to click and follow the question.

Comment: Yes, favorites gets defined by the favorite tags. However, favorite option is shown only when I have done some activity on that question.

Comment: You add a question to favorites by clicking on the star below the question's vote count.

Comment: Great! This is what I was looking for. Thank you. Don't know how I missed it so far.

Comment: You're welcome. It's a great tool.